# How to rotate text with imagemagick?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have a long image [source pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWbI8.jpg) and I want to add text to every subimage, but when add text to the book, I failed, the final image and code:

[image: the final image]

```
convert src.jpg -gravity north -pointsize 53 -fill white    -annotate +0+520   "I love you,don't leave me " -annotate +0+1146   "Do not be a programmer,ok?" -annotate +0+1772   "fuck u！" -annotate +0+3024  "too simple "  -draw 'translate 340,3340  rotate 21 text 0,0 "Javascript Action"'  final.jpg
```

Can any one help? Thanks

Comment: i want to change to newline when the book name  is too long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your example, you should use -annotate for all the text placements and rotations in Imagemagick rather than using -draw for the last one. This will keep your last text from going off the image. Try this:

```
convert src.jpg -gravity north -pointsize 53 -fill white -annotate +0+520 "I love you,don't leave me " -annotate +0+1146 "Do not be a programmer,ok?" -annotate +0+1772 "xxxx x" -annotate +0+3024 "too simple " -gravity north -annotate 21x21+0+3340 "Javascript Action" final1.jpg
```

[image]

See https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#annotate

**Please do not use vulgarisms in examples.**

If you want to have text wrap, then you need to use caption: to create a new image with transparent background for each text. Then composite the new text image onto your background image at the desired locations. You can control when it wraps, by the -size Wx argument. Here I use the full width of your image, that is, -size 1000x.

```
convert src.jpg \
-pointsize 53 -background none -fill white -size 1000x \
\( -gravity center caption:"I love you,don't leave me" \) -gravity north -geometry +0+420 -compose over -composite \
\( -gravity center caption:"Do not be a programmer,ok?" \) -gravity north -geometry +0+1046 -compose over -composite \
\( -gravity center caption:"xxxx x" \) -gravity north -geometry +0+1672 -compose over -composite \
\( -gravity center caption:"too simple" \) -gravity north -geometry +0+2924 -compose over -composite \
\( -gravity center caption:"Javascript Action" -rotate 21 \) -gravity north -geometry +0+3240 -compose over -composite \
final2.jpg
```

[image]

Or to make it wrap earlier than the width of the your image, I set -size 500x

```
convert src.jpg \
-pointsize 53 -background none -fill white -size 500x \
\( -gravity center caption:"I love you,don't leave me" \) -gravity north -geometry +0+420 -compose over -composite \
\( -gravity center caption:"Do not be a programmer,ok?" \) -gravity north -geometry +0+1046 -compose over -composite \
\( -gravity center caption:"xxxx x" \) -gravity north -geometry +0+1672 -compose over -composite \
\( -gravity center caption:"too simple" \) -gravity north -geometry +0+2924 -compose over -composite \
\( -gravity center caption:"Javascript Action" -rotate 21 \) -gravity north -geometry +0+3240 -compose over -composite \
final3.jpg
```

[image]

See

https://imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#caption
https://imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/#convert

ADDITION:

To blur the text, just add -blur after caption:

```
convert src.jpg \
-pointsize 53 -background none -fill white -size 500x \
\( -gravity center caption:"I love you,don't leave me" -blur 0x3 \) -gravity north -geometry +0+420 -compose over -composite \
\( -gravity center caption:"Do not be a programmer,ok?" -blur 0x3 \) -gravity north -geometry +0+1046 -compose over -composite \
\( -gravity center caption:"xxxx x" -blur 0x3 \) -gravity north -geometry +0+1672 -compose over -composite \
\( -gravity center caption:"too simple" -blur 0x3 \) -gravity north -geometry +0+2924 -compose over -composite \
\( -gravity center caption:"Javascript Action" -blur 0x3 -rotate 21 \) -gravity north -geometry +0+3240 -compose over -composite \
final4.jpg
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is working now.But can the book name  text place on the center of the book face?

Comment: gravity north cannot put the text on the center of the  book face

Comment: I tried this :convert src.jpg -gravity north -pointsize 53 -font ./font/MSYHBD.TTC -fill white -annotate +0+520 "I love you,don't leave me " -annotate +0+1146 "Do not be a programmer,ok?" -annotate +0+1772 "xxxx x" -annotate +0+3024 "too simple "   miff:-|convert - -gravity NorthWest  -fill '#824a0f' -pointsize 50 -font ./font/MSYHBD.TTC \( -draw "translate 340,3340 rotate 22  text 0,0 'Javascript\n Action'" -blur 0X10 \)  final.jpg    ,i want to blur the text but this  blur the whole image ,and cannot change line.

Comment: See ADDITION in my answer above. No need to pipe nor to use -draw. In this case, you must use caption:

Comment: I didn't get it. Was it the "21x21" that made the text rotate? What, 21 degrees clockwise? Why repeat the 21? And why repeat the "gravity north" if it was already there since the beginning?

Comment: -rotate 21 is what cause the rotation. I do not see any 21x21 (unless that was in a -annotate 21x21. then that would cause rotation). When using gravity center, then gravity north, you have to keep resetting the gravity, since once it is used it will stay the same until you change it.